# How do I get dynamic index position for a specific character for a input text?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, angularjs, string

let's assume an input string has given, for a particular character like '$' you want to add dynamically in the text field , so I want to find the index of a current character like **'$'** then it's not working properly like initially if I give '$'in any position, its reflection the position, example if I give **'random text$'** it returns **index 11** but if you type '$'in between text like **'random $text$'** then **it should return 7, but it returns 12**,**so by achieving 7 I need to give extra space like 'random $ text$'**, **so dynamically how to get the index position of a current character($), whether It's added in first, middle, last of the text**

```
  let string = "random $text$";
  let newArray = string.split("");
  let store = string.length % 2 !== 0
    ? newArray.findLastIndex((x) => x === "$")
    : newArray.findIndex((x) => x === "$");

  console.log(store);
```

Comment: Do you want to get the `$` which is preceded by some characters and not a space? I'm assuming you are using `text$` as a placeholder to be replaced by something else? It's not clear what you're trying to exactly

Comment: Can't you just use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) -> `"random $text$".indexOf("$")`

Comment: am i missing a question mark in the text? Text looks like a badly formatted piece of code :-)

Comment: acctually indexof is giveing only 1st index not the current index if i write at last

Comment: What do you mean by *current character*? Can you please add some sample inputs and expected outputs for the same? It's not clear what you're trying to do. (This also seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you just want to add a space after first occurance of `$` in the input string. You can simply achieve that by using [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method instead of looking for `index` as If `pattern` in replace function is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced. The original string is left unchanged.

Live Demo **:**

```js
function checkIndex(e) {
  const val = e.target.value;
  console.log(val.replace('$', '$ '));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val" onBlur="checkIndex(event)"/>
```

**Update :** Here is the workaround solution but not a good practice to do. For demo, I am using an input and after getting the index, I am replacing the `$` with some other character so that I can get the index of current/newly added  `$`.

Demo **:**

```js
function checkIndex(e) {
  const val = e.target.value;
  if (/$/.test(val)) {
    console.log(val.indexOf('$'))
    document.getElementById('val').value = val.replaceAll('$', '-')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val" onBlur="checkIndex(event)"/>
```

Comment: acctually i want the logic of a dynamic taking current index position like 'Text$' its return 4  then '$Text$' it should be return o position like that again if i provide '$Te$xt$' it should be give 3 index position like that

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you check for first index/last based on if the total length is even/uneven. However if you want to get all indices you can use a reducer.

```js
const string = "random $text$";
const charToFind = "$";
// Get all indexes of char charToFind in string
let indexes = [...string].reduce((previous, current, i) => {
  // Checks if current value is equal to charToFind otherwise return previous
  return current === charToFind ? [...previous, i] : previous;
}, []);
```

EDIT:
Per OPs new requirements in the comments this is what I could come up with. However its a bit overcomplicated, and will not always work.

```js
// This only take to account of one change, it will not work with paste etc.
const findChar = (newState: string, oldState: string, lastKnownIndices: number[], charToFind: string) => {
  // Find first diff between old and new state
  const firstDiffIndex = newState
    .split("")
    .findIndex((char, index) => char !== oldState[index]);

  // Check if we have added or removed a char 
  const isCharAdded = newState.length > oldState.length;
  // Update last known indices, 
  let newIndices = lastKnownIndices.map((index) => {
    if (index >= firstDiffIndex) {
      return isCharAdded ? index + 1 : index - 1;
    }
    return index;
  }).filter((index) => {
    // Remove indices that are no longer valid
    return newState[index] === charToFind;
  });

  // If we added a char, check if it is the char we are looking for
  if (isCharAdded && newState[firstDiffIndex] === charToFind) {
    newIndices = [firstDiffIndex, ...newIndices]
  }

  return {
    newIndices,
    newState,
    lastIndex: newIndices.length > 0 ? newIndices[0] : -1
  }
}

const noCharsToFind = findChar("random text", "random tex", [], "$")
console.log(noCharsToFind)

const addedOneCharToFind = findChar("random $text", noCharsToFind.newState, noCharsToFind.newIndices, "$")
console.log(addedOneCharToFind)

const addedOneMoreCharToFind = findChar("random $text$", addedOneCharToFind.newState, addedOneCharToFind.newIndices, "$")
console.log(addedOneMoreCharToFind)

const removedOneCharToFind = findChar("random text$", addedOneMoreCharToFind.newState, addedOneMoreCharToFind.newIndices, "$")
console.log(removedOneCharToFind)
```

[Here is a link to playground if you want to test more cases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsEsGdQPYDsA2BPUAXAhgawKZYKjYDGpCArkpogGaJKGmTZIDm%20ANKNLQO7QUKUEgQCEAJ1yhBmSKAAO2WJkL5MpAHQAoCklWg60JABMAwq0mgAvKAAUTfgGUcagFyhVkk%20x4IUU1dsDy9MHw4eFBVMAGkxfiQASTNoUnxYTyRKAFsAI3xJAG0AXR4WbElwBAAxE1NPb18ASlsAPlAAbx1QUBBQOrMjaElDU2g6BgLMfnx8JERAkiGnMJD8HtB9Q2NRzAARCboU03wAD1tRfBc3Dd7erVhFFD57ACI35s2H4zMT8-s9gqkh49XOrRsHWBoAAhDY7AEgrcimCziVmgBuHSbfqWfCkGQTWSEVgAN0I2FMp1MiGsknwOQQ5Jp2C2VlAm22tDglkqAEEqfgaXYnME1FoUPN2PJQB1EWL8BKpfIsb1%20gBVRSmdagaKGXAJBb1NIZHibSW0JwnE3wOx6uKG63pWBaHLYRSA1EQjrde68Bj2VGyuy7VSHSb-M6tX1%200D0zCUSRG2C8yQC6mgAD8vDM51AAGpQABGUCeIMAWmLqvuAF9vnGNImjbmztWa80tMYUGpJJ6W96uvX%20gAlBlMwjG51YVi0SqEMS65Ccayk7AvUz1%20NNq43dYolslWzwtmVaqDUxtzHYtVgJIMWYkQUsk8gtn4wkMPi8eDyZjsh9zouCC4L4RhSJsRKBimVjpkKoAAGTwTuCpFKGBxHJGh7wnYwJnvU0b1laqRTnYqEjGGGEtjwWg0UR4zOiUmx1psW5JoOfp0TaXCEdcCrcX69qRlk1xOhkSocDKHQAAxZjuomwEUUmHp45ZFkxOjMVyogIKmsB4UMIb1Km7ySGwpgIDkWDnJgbw8G8plmBZVlnLZoClHZAAknx6MgsABIqKAIOwjg6VYem1Ph2JaZS1IAPJMKm%20nCsMZjGfZZlOR5ahnDZPBiLpSVaKKtx5aFlTheeRUicRpqgG8XlfNs-kSkF9gxUK8X4IlEVmF8PkGLOT6dQAslIXVWElly-BYVgmRlllZdZXk8O1pidd1lXFesK1DQlE09aYVX8PJnneU1kotcFq0jWNG2Rf1hj0oyzLrft55TUZs3pY5lnZZgy2PnFTCjfSd1mEdfGAx1wO3W99RHSddUNQ9zWBcFT3jmte2ngdXxAA)

Comment: basically in reducer all the occurrence is there in a array form like [7, 12]
 but i need only the ,current or last added indexes like 7

Comment: @SougataMukherjee what do you mean by *"last added indexes"*? Is this an input textbox where you are calling a change event?

Comment: acctually i want the logic of a dynamic taking current index position like 'Text$' its return 4  then '$Text$' it should be return o position like that again if i provide '$Te$xt$' it should be give 3 index position like that

Comment: @SougataMukherjee is this logic inside an input change event handler? If a `$` is added inside the text, you want to get where was the most recent `$` was added?

Comment: yes I know if you taking the on Change event like e.nativeEvent.data here you can get the current character but not the current position  like i just want the newly added charecter $ position whether it begining middle or end of the string

Comment: That seems super overcomplicated, with alot of edgecases. Why do you need this, could you share your code on where and why. Might be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: @SougataMukherjee man, can you please share full context of your code? HOW IS THIS STRING VALUE CHANGED?  You keep saying "*current position*". How does it change from `'Text$'` to `'$Text$'` ? Is it coming from an input?

Comment: in my application it s taking value from props like props.value in input field so I just added here a variable string

Comment: @SougataMukherjee Please edit the question and add the full context. You don't need to add the entire components. Just a minimal version which shows HOW this value is changed from x to y. And, WHY do you need the index of the newly added `$`.